# Timestamp in Hive tables keeps changing

Tags: oracle11g, hive, sqoop

I have a HIVE table which stores timestamp in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm::ss.S format. But I have noticed that The value in such columns keeps changing, e.g. the value that I sqooped was '2016-01-**25 00**:00:00.0' but sometimes (not always) this value is shown as '2016-01-**24 19**:00:00.0'.

To make matters worse, this does not happen in all tables at the same time. Sometimes *table1* would have the correct format and *table2*, the incorrect one (2016-01-**24 19**:00:00.0) and vice versa

I don't know if this is relevant, but we recently moved from ORACLE to HIVE. In the oracle table the date column was of type 'DATE' which stored datda as **25-JAN-16** but in HIVE the column is of type 'TIMESTAMP' and stores data as **2016-01-25 00:00:00.0**.

*The timestamp is correct when I sqoop the data but is sometimes incorrect when I check it out later.*

Could someone please tell me how I could fix or work around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because of the timezone problem. Try using timezone UDFs in hive and check whether you are getting it right.

eg. `to_utc_timestamp`